# Stateless Functional Component prop of type function doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I don't know how to accurately describe the issue i'm facing so the title probably makes little sense.

I am using react 15.4.2, mobx 3.0.0

I have a stateless functional `Blah` component which accepts an object `thing` as a prop.
`thing` has properties which are observable.
As expected, when a different instance of `thing` is passed in, the Blah component updates accordingly.
The `Blah` Component has another component that is basically a wrapper for **react-dropzone-component**  called `DzComponent`
One of the parameters passed to react-dropzone-component is the `success` event handler. This is called when we drop something and it successfully uploads.

The issue is this sequence of events:

- `Blah` called with thing instance `A`
- `DzComponent` correctly gets `handleImageUpload` reference. i.e. upon success, when we call `props.thing.observable` it is referring to instance `A`
- `Blah` called with thing instance `B`
- `DzComponent` seems to still refer to old `handleImageUpload` reference. i.e. upon success, `props.thing.observable` is still referring to instance `A` instead of the intended instance `B`

How do I get the event handler to update the correct instance?

Blah.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';

function Blah(props) {

    function handleImageUpload(evt, res) {      
        props.thing.observable = res.image_url
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>blah blah blah {props.thing.otherObservable}</div>
            <DzComponent success={handleImageUpload}></DzComponent>
        </div>
    )
}    
Blah.propTypes={
    thing: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default observer(Blah)
```

DzComponent.jsz

```
import React from 'react';
import DropzoneComponent from 'react-dropzone-component';
function DzComponent(props) {
    return <DropzoneComponent></DropzoneComponent>
}

export default observer(DzComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked http://jsbin.com/bulubuwuzo/1/edit?js,console,output

Everything works ok

Maybe you have a bug on `DzComponent` or `DropzoneComponent` component

Comment: hmmm. thanks for putting that together. good to know that it should work. I'll re-review my code.